# C: How can character o/p be a string

Tags: c

My question is when I give :

i/p - abcde

how i get output - abcde .

I mean C is a character so shouldn't o/p also be an single character .
Why is o/p coming out to be be string cant understand.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    char c;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        printf("%c",c);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Appreciate Help.
I know I should use int for c here.

Comment: Your output is inside a loop. The loop runs 6 times, printing 1 character each time, for a total of 6 characters (this is including the ENTER).

Comment: what did you expect to see as output?

Comment: "I know I should use int for c here" ... so use `int`!

Comment: Detail: In C, a _string_ is an array of characters up to and including the null character.  Output is not a _string_, but a series of characters - one at a time (although likely buffered).  `printf("%c",c);` was called 5 times, each time with a new value on `c`, each time printing 1 character.

Comment: I got it that it was series of characters but why weren't the characters being printed simultaneously. I mean it gets one character now it should print that character and now another character and so on ?

Comment: Try doing `printf("%\n", c);` instead and you will get what you expected

Comment: @UditArora: Because the characters weren't *read* simultaneously - they way the loop is written, you read a character with `getchar()`, print it with `printf()`, then read the *next* character with `getchar()`, print *that* character with `printf()`, etc.

Comment: Thank u everyone got the answer :)